# Why is jQuery so big when I download it?

Tags: jquery

I went to jquery.com and downloaded the latest version. I picked the production:

```
31kb (minified and zipped)
```

but when it downloads to my disk it's 90KB. Can someone explain. Am I downloading the wrong way or something?

Comment: jQuery minified is in fact about 90kb if I recall correctly. Unminified is over 200kb.

Comment: did you notice the **and Gzipped** part ? If you set your server to send resources gzipped, that is what will get transmitted (*provided the browser that requests the file supports it*). more at http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size specified is how large it will be if you are using compression for your static files on the web server.

What you download is the minified version. It's not zipped, because the web server will do that before sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It says Gzipped, not Zipped.

31kb refers to the amount of data you have to download, when taking minification *and* the webserver's Gzip compression into account.

When the file arrives at your PC, it is de-Gzipped for use. However, it's still minified, so it's around 90kb rather than 200-odd kb.

Have a read through [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/).

**Summary** The number on the website indicates the *download size*, not the *file size*.

Answer (score 1):

The word "minified" means that comments where removed etc etc that leads to a size of 90kb
The word "zipped" means that if the server serve jquery gzipped you get a size of "31kb"

I always use this:
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js.
The chances are high that the visitor already have jquery in cache.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't suited to be a SO question. I mean, all it takes is simple reading - it says "minified AND zipped". When you download it it is not zipped if you want to see the plain text version, is it?